# Обширный туториал по сборке/установке OpenCV для MinGW (C++), и дальнейшей работы через NotePad++

Tags: c++, opencv, обработка-изображений

Несколько дней пытаюсь установить и подключить OpenCV.  Большинство уроков начинаются с того, что у автора уже установлен OpenCV, либо же уроки для OpenCV в Python. Или посоветуйте библиотек для работы с файлами изображений, по типу "CImg.h", и уроков по ним. Библиотеки можно максимально простые, мне достаточно отрисовки по пикселям. В C# и Python это делалось гораздо проще, но мне требуется производительность C++.

Comment: OpenCV есть в списке пакетов MSYS2, можно поставить оттуда готовый (вместе с нормальной версией MinGW). Инструкция: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075

Comment: `winget install msys2.msys2`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat пока всё идет хорошо. Я установил OpenCv, команду на этом сайте https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-opencv. Добавил в PATH путь к MSYS2/bin. Как мне теперь скомпилировать файл через g++?

Comment: Установите гцц командой `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` (именно так, а не `pacman -S gcc`). В `PATH` нужно добавлять `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`. Дальше, флаги компилятора подскажет команда `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv4` (из пакета `mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config`).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, огромное спасибо. Все заработало.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ответы - в ответы.